# Let $G$ be a connected graph, then $G$ is a tree iff $G$ has no cycles

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-verification, trees

> Prove the following: Let $G$ be a connected graph, then $G$ is a tree $\iff$ $G$ has no cycles.

$\Rightarrow$ If $G$ is connected and a tree then by the definition of tree it has no cycles.

$\Leftarrow$ $G$ is connected and acyclic, prove $G$ is a tree. Suppose $G$ isn't a tree, then it must be either disconnected or has cycles which contradicts the given.

It seems too easy so I'm doubting myself...

Definition for a tree: If $n=1$ then $G$ is a tree. If $|V|>1$ then $G$ is a tree if G is given from from a tree $T$ by adding $1$ vertex and $1$ edge connected to it.

Comment: What is the definition of tree that you are using?

Comment: Everything is right. :) By definition of tree := connected graph without cycles.

Comment: @PedroM. see edit. We saw several definitions but the one I added was the first.

Comment: I see. Then your proof is not correct, as you are using the result (that a tree is a connected graph with no cycles) to prove itself. You need to prove this by induction on the number of vertices of $G$.

Comment: @PedroM. isn't the part that $G$ is connected given for proving both sides?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand your question. In any case, what I meant is that you should try the following: for a (connected) graph with $1$ vertex, clearly $G$ is a tree iff it has no cycles. Now suppose, by induction, that this holds for graphs with $n-1$ vertices, and consider a graph with $n$ vertices. You have to show that, if it is a tree (with the definition you gave) then it has no cycles; conversely, if $G$ has no cycles, you have to show that there exists a vertex $v$ such that $G - v$ is a tree.

Comment: @PedroM. I see both are wrong then... I meant can't we assume that $G$ is connected for both $\Rightarrow, \Leftarrow$?

Comment: You can, or better said, you have to assume that $G$ is connected (especially for $\Leftarrow$); but that does not let you avoid the induction step, because the definition of tree is inductive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly a tree with 1 vertex has no cycles. For a connected tree with $k$ vertices, pick a vertex that was most recently added in some sequence constructing the tree. If we remove the vertex, there are no cycles by induction. If we had a cycle when we attached the new vertex, then the cycle would have to contain the new vertex, which means the new vertex would have to have degree at least 2, contradicting the choice of vertex. Thus a tree has no cycles by induction.

Suppose now that $G$ is a connected graph with no cycles. If $G$ has one vertex, then it is a tree. Otherwise, suppose there is a vertex $v$ of degree 1. Then $G-v$ is a connected graph with no cycles and hence a tree by induction. It easily follows that $G$ is a tree.

Thus we may assume that every vertex has degree at least 2. Choose a vertex $w$ such that $G-w$ is connected and let $u,v$ be distinct vertices adjacent to $w$. Then there is a path from $u$ to $v$ not containing $w$ since $G-w$ is connected, and adjoining $w$ to this path creates a cycle. Thus a connected graph with no cycles has at least one vertex of degree 1, and we are done.

Here is justification that $w$ can be chosen so that $G-w$ is connected:

Suppose $G=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$. Set $w_1=v_1$. Inductively, assume $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_p\}$ is a set of $p$ distinct vertices such that for all $p'\leq p$ we have that $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_{p'}\}$ is connected. Let $\{v_{i_1},v_{i_2},\ldots,v_{i_{k-p}}\}$ be the remaining vertices in $G$. If there is no $q\leq p$ and $j\leq k-p$ such that $\{w_q,v_{i_j}\}$ is an edge in $G$, then $\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_p\}$ and $\{v_{i_1},\ldots,v_{i_{k-p}}\}$ are disjoint, have no edges between them, and their union is $G$, implying that $G$ is disconnected. Thus there exists a $w_{p+1}\in \{v_{i_1},\ldots,v_{i_{k-p}}\}$ such that $\{w_1,\ldots,w_{p+1}\}$ is connected, and we are done.

Comment: Your proof is essentially correct, but don't you need to justify why there is a path from $u$ to $v$ that **does not go through $w$** in the last paragraph?

Comment: @Pedro fixed. Took an hour because I was shoveling snow!

Comment: Again, everything is correct, but I still feel it's lacking justification on why there exists a vertex $w$ such that $G - w$ is connected (keep in mind that the OP may possibly be taking an introductory course in graph theory, considering the level of the question at hand)

Comment: @PedroM. I would guess that that was something they were allowed to assume, but I have added the proof anyway.